# Adding same resource in multiple resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I am a novice in Azure and currently learning about resource groups. According to their documentation, it says "a resource can only be a member of a single resource group", but I just created 2 different resource groups and named them 'msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg' and 'msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg2' under Free Subscription and I added Virtual Network as a resource in both of them.

I have named the network separately as well. The tutorial says to add vitual network resource in just 'msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg', I created another resource group just to see what error I get if I add same resource in another resource group.

The virtual network resource was added successfully in both the resource groups. So doesn't it contradict the statement: "a resource can only be a member of a single resource group"?

A bit confused here. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

What you did is create 2 virtual networks, both of which are in a single resource group.
A single virtual network can only be in a single resource group.
You can create more of similar resources in different resource groups.

Comment: @junnas, I did create 2 different resource groups 'msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg' and ''msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg2'. I can still see in my azure account. To avoid confusion I added one more Vitrual Network in  'msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg'. So now 1 RG has 2 virtual networks and another RG has just 1 virtual network. I also name those virtual networks as vm-net-1, vm-net-2, vm-net-3

Comment: I understand that, but you have essentially RG1 with VNET1 and RG2 with VNET2. Those virtual networks are not the same resource. They are different instances of the same resource type.

Comment: @junnas, I see. so what makes these instances different? The names we give them like VNET-1 and VNET-2? which is why we can add them to different resource groups?
In that case, what did Microsoft mean by saying this: "a resource can only be a member of a single resource group"?

Comment: It just means that there is a one-to-many relationship between resource groups and individual resources. The full id for a resource is actually something like /subscriptions/sub-id/resourceGroups/rg-name/resource-type/resource-name.

Comment: And when you create a resource like a vnet, you can only choose one resource group.

Comment: so in simple words, cannot use the name vnet in different resource groups, must be named differently to create a different instance of the same resource type.

Comment: When you create a new resource, it is by definition a different instance of that resource type already. If it thinks you can't use this name because it is already in use, it'll tell you before you create it.

Comment: My apologies, just a small confusion, when you said "And when you create a resource like a vnet, you can only choose one resource group." it does mean I can create the same resource with a different name to add it in different resource group, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can create a vnet with a different name and put it in another resource group, or you could put it in the same resource group as the first one.

Comment: that helps. thanks a lot for clearing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

just create two storage accounts in two RGs  and create a container in both  , and try to upload two different files in each conatiner , come after 2 mins and you will see that each conatiner has  only the files that you uploaded , if a resource could have been connected to two or more reource groups than this storage accounts should have similar files